# Ошибка при компоновке проекта

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio

Помогите исправить ошибку:

`LNK2001    неразрешенный внешний символ "sqlite3_close"`

Я почитал про эту проблему, все говорят, что надо добавить файлы `sqlite3.c` и `sqlite3.h`, а также подключить файл `*.lib`. Я все добавил и подключил:

`#pragma comment (lib, "sqlite3.lib")`

и все равно ничего не изменилось.

Comment: я бы рад помочь, но не вижу что вы писали, потому не могу понять где ошибка

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я скачал проект с Github и там надо было установить sqlite3 я сделал все, что вверху написано и всеравно ошибка не убралас

Comment: Может, нужно указать, что это сишные функции? Окружить `#include` конструкцией `extern "C"`?